# Jquery Deferred not triggering done or when

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I have 2 ajax calls that I am attaching via $.when to perform some tasks when they are finished.

The code looks like this:

```
function ajaxCall(url, targetDiv) {
    dfd = new $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url:url
        success : function(data) {
            dfd.resolve(data, targetDiv);
        }
    })
    return dfd.promise()
}

d = ajaxCall('/somewhere/', 'myDiv');
d2 = ajaxCall('/somewhere/else', 'myNewDiv');
$.when(d, d2).then(function(){alert('all done');})
```

In this scenario we never have the alert all done called.  We are following roughly the outline on https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/

When checking this we can see that neither d nor d2 will ever call done (if we attach a done to them) however the success part of the ajax call is called.

Comment: Why don't you just `return $.ajax(...)`?

Comment: need to pass more parameters to the resolve statement

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon OP wants to attach `targetDiv` to the response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax analyzer mode... STOP!

```
function ajaxCall(url, targetDiv) {
    dfd = new $.Deferred(); // <-- Wait, a global variable?
```

Second `ajaxCall(...)` is setting a different `Deferred` instance, and first deferred won't never be resolved (*you're setting the same variable twice, so `.resolve(...)` is called on the second `ajaxCall(...)` function call only and you're not resolving the first deferred object because it's gone!*).

Solution:

```
function ajaxCall(url, targetDiv) {
    var dfd = new $.Deferred(); // <-- Oh! A local variable... :)
```

Do you want a good suggestion? Always declare variables with `var`, since variables declared in a function scope will be added to the function instance, instead of `window` object:

```
// Both sentences are equivalent in a function scope (or in the global scope)
a = "hello";
window.a = "hello";
```

Comment: @Marco I had to double, triple re-read the code until a very stupid detail was found by my mental syntax analyzer hahaha. Anyway I'm glad it solved your question :)